# Apple Auto Renwable Purchase, What's The possible Reason For Renewal Failure With Receipt Field expiration_intent value is 4

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription

We are implementing **introductory offers** for apple auto-renewable subscriptions and test it in *sandbox environment*. Although we are able to purchase auto-renewable product with discounted price, **the Apple Store failed to renew the subscription**.
So i checked the receipt, here is the `pending_renewal_info` field

```js
"pending_renewal_info":[
  {
    "expiration_intent":"4", 
    "auto_renew_product_id":"xxx",
    "original_transaction_id":"1000000548545827", 
    "is_in_billing_retry_period":"1", 
    "product_id":"xxx",
    "auto_renew_status":"1"
  }]
}
```

and apple's offical document about `expiration_intent` value 4

> 4 The product was not available for purchase at the time of renewal.

**The product was not available**, i don't get this, what does it mean? what's the possible reason for the unavailability? **If the product is not available, how can i purchase it successfully?**

Comment: If you withdrew the IAP from sale between the previous renewal and now

Comment: no, i didn't withdraw, actually i did nothing but waiting for next renewal. In sandbox environment, i just need to wait a few minutes if everything is ok

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were asking what would cause a status 4 in production.  In the sandbox, Apple sometimes gives you various renewal failures so you can test